# Android: Remove all layout animations

Tags: java, android

So I've noticed Android generates a slight fade between activities which really bugs me and I was wondering if there was any way to get rid of it and just have it "snap" to the next screen with no animation at all?

I've looked around but I can't find anything that answers my question really. I was under the assumption that it would be XML based but I saw this guy trying to do it programmatically here:
[How do I eliminate the delay before an LayoutTransition animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225367/how-do-i-eliminate-the-delay-before-an-layouttransition-animation) but doing what he did (applying a "blank" animation) didn't seem to change anything.

Could something point me in the right direction? Ta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant control is achieved using styles and themes. This way, you can control this on a per-`Application` as well as per-`Activity` basis.

styles.xml (`WhateverTheme` being the Android theme you implicitly or explicitly chose for your app):

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <style
        name="MyWhateverTheme"
        parent="@android:style/WhateverTheme">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyActivityAnim</item>
    </style>

    <style
        name="MyActivityAnim">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Of course, you can also specify custom `@animation`s this way.

In your Manifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:theme="@style/MyWhateverTheme" >
```

and to change it for a particular `Activity`:

```
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/SomeOtherTheme" >
```

Comment: @Michael I was really wondering why you would choose the wrong concept. You sounded definitely like you wanted to _style_ your app in a unique fashion. Setting a flag on a per-`Intent` basis is a completely broken approach to do that in terms of redundancy/maintainability. As a concept, it simply doesn't match your objectives. But then again, there are dozens of people here who are looking for just _any_ solution. Probably the same who later tell averyone how broken Android is because it lacks this and that feature. Anyhow. Now you know. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: How does this answer address the OP's requirement to remove _all_ layout animations?

Comment: There will be no animation if you apply the flag

Comment: I play around with all the flags to see how they work. I am glad this help you.

Comment: @Michael And I was thinking you were looking for a way to get rid of all animations throughout all of your app. Seems I wasted my time.